# Call AWS lambda from .Net Console application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a .Net console application running on EC2 in which I want to call AWS lambda to execute a long list of 10000 tasks.  These tasks can have a chance to success and fail, however, I only need at least 5000 successful tasks.  Queuing will not be a part of the picture because I want the response code from the lambda in my console app. Is it possible to trigger AWS lambda from a .Net console application?  Is there any configuration on user or role when calling the lambda if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first part of the question: yes, its possible to invoke a lambda function from a .net core application - you can do it directly using the .net sdk, or thru REST calls using the aws api-gateway (assuming you setup the api-gateway to lambda link first).

> Is there any configuration on user or role when calling the lambda if it is possible?

I don't understand that part of the question:  but you will need to use some aws credentials to invoke lambda from a .net core application, and those credentials will need to have sufficient rights to make the call.

Comment: Thanking for taking the time to answer my question.  I would like to point out that the question is referring to call lambda internally without calling API gateway first.  The reason is to avoid exposing the lambda to the internet and suppose the lambda would be in a VPC.  I know that to execute lambda, we might need "invoke lambda" permission.  This is setup if a lambda is calling another lambda.  I just don't know how would it be possible if a .net console application can invoke a lambda function.